# Action in controller received empty model from Html.BeginForm - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, html.beginform

I have stucked for 3 days. There is nowhere I had been looking for this problem. When I submit the form, Controller action method doesnt get the model.

My base view Login.cshtml

```
@{
    string durum = ViewBag.Style;

    switch (durum)
    {
        case "Login":
            Html.RenderAction("_Login", "Dashboard");
            break;
        case "LostPassword":
            Html.RenderAction("_LostPassword", "Dashboard");
            break;
        case "RegisterForm":
            Html.RenderAction("_RegisterForm", "Dashboard");
            break;
        default:
            Html.RenderAction("_Login", "Dashboard");
            break;
    }
}
```

One of my partial view _LostPassword.cshtml

```
@model HaberSitesi._Entities.Kullanici

@using (Html.BeginForm("LostPassword", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "forget-form", @style = "display:block" }))

{
    if (TempData["ForgotPassword"] != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-warning ">
            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
            <span>@TempData["ForgotPassword"]</span>

        </div>
    }
    <h3>Şifrenizi mi unuttunuz ?</h3>
    <p> Şifrenizi almak için lütfen E-Posta adresinizi giriniz. </p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EPosta, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix", @type = "email", @autocomplete = "off", @placeholder = "Eposta", Name = "email" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EPosta)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        @Html.ActionLink("Geri Dön", "Login", "Dashboard", new { }, new { @type = "button", @id = "back-btn", @class = "btn grey-salsa btn-outline" })

        <button type="submit" class="btn green pull-right"> Gönder </button>
    </div>
}
```

And the action in controller DashboardController.cs

```
 public ActionResult LostPassword()
        {
            VeriTransfer();
            return View("Login");
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LostPassword(Kullanici kullanici)
        {
            string kullaniciEposta = kullanici.EPosta;

            Kullanici user = _kullaniciBll.Get(kullaniciEposta);

            if (user != null)
            {
                TempData["ForgotPassword"] = "Şifreniz e-posta adresinize gönderildi.";
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["ForgotPassword"] = "Kayıtlarımızda e-posta adresiniz bulunamadı";
            }
            VeriTransfer();
            return View("Login");
        }
```

When I click submit button, I cant get any data (Kullanici kullanici) in controller. Every property comes null or default data value from model.

Note: Maybe my codes could have some other mistakes which are irrelevant with my problem. I just wonder why I get empty model. Thanks at least you have read my problem.

Comment: Remove `new { Name = "email" }` Never attempt to override the `name` attribute generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods

Comment: That helped me thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property is called `EPosta` but you changed the name of it to `Name="email"`.So when the POST action happens it sends a property called `email` to the controller action and your `Kullanici` object expects a property called `EPosta`

Both of these will fix your problem:

1. Change `Name="email"` to `Name="EPosta"` or
2. Remove `Name="email"` completely

But like Stephen said it's better to remove it completely,because if you rename your property to `EPosta2` in future and forget to change the name to `Name="EPosta2"` your POST will no longer work

Comment: I have understood clearly now. While I have been trying to implement a template, I had to change the name attribute for jquery validation. Now I have changed jquery validation rules based on my model. Thank you so much.